# Get Most Recent Record

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

The question speaks for itself, for the most part. I have 2 fields in a table, Date and Value.
By the most recent date, I would like to use the dollar value. I would like to get these values by means of VBA code.

Is this possible with a `DLookup` or `DMax`, or something similar?

What I have now searches dates quarterly, however quarterly is not the correct solution I've come to figure out, as the quarterly updates are sent out too late to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TOP 1` in a query sorted by `Date` in descending order.

```
SELECT TOP 1 y.Date, y.Value
FROM YourTable AS y
ORDER BY y.Date DESC;
```

Comment: HansUp, is this executable in a "longer" query with more than just that data? For example, here's my query:
`
SELECT TOP 1 Nav.NAV_Date, Nav.NetAssetValue, PlanTbl.PlanDesc, AwardTbl.AwardDate, AwardTbl.AwardUnits, [AwardUnits]*[NetAssetValue] AS [Current Value], Count(AwardTbl.AwardID) AS CountOfAwardID
FROM NAV_Tbl AS Nav, PlanTbl INNER JOIN AwardTbl ON PlanTbl.PlanID = AwardTbl.PlanID
GROUP BY PlanTbl.PlanDesc, AwardTbl.AwardDate, AwardTbl.AwardUnits, [AwardUnits]*[NetAssetValue], Nav.NAV_Date
ORDER BY AwardTbl.AwardDate;
`

Comment: I'm unclear about that one.  Perhaps you can start with a simpler `GROUP BY` query, and save it as a named query.  Then create another query for `TOP 1` whose data source is the first query.